# Adding a unique id to a csv output

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

my codes successfully converts an xml file to csv ending the data  created with a comma(,)

sample data

```
<Addy>
 <Rowinfo>
<LD>FLAT</LD>
<L>1</L>
<Th> Passage</Th>
</Rowinfo>
 <Addy>
```

produces a csv output of

```
FLAT,1,Passage,
```

when this file is opened and a column is added to give it unique ID such as 1,2,3...

```
1,FLAT,1,Passage,
2,FLAT,1,Passage,
```

the commas at the end disappears producing

```
 1,FLAT,1,Passage
 2,FLAT,2,okete
```

can XSLT assign these unique numbers automatically in the process of producing a csv output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add two lines...

Add this second line to your first template...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:value-of select="'Id,'" />
 etc.
```

Add this second line to your second template...

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),',')" />
 etc.
```

And now you get csv output like...

```
Id,LD,L,Th
1,FLAT,1, Passage
```

...where the first column (*'Id'*) is a unique ID. (An ordinal row number, in point of fact.)

Answer (score 1):

Functions used for XPath can also be used in XSLT.  Possibly one of these three may help:

- fn:Id (aka fn:element-with-id)
- fn:Id-ref
- fn:position

That last one looks particularly promising.  If you execute it in relation to the `RowInfo` node, you will probably get a nice clean ascending numeric value from it.

Comment: @ Brent Arias, would be glad if you could take me through that, as i intend to add it to the following codes